# ThreadSanitizer date race test for Windows

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, thread-safety

Who knows [ThreadSanitizer](http://code.google.com/p/data-race-test/wiki/ThreadSanitizer)? Does anyone use this tool for windows (xp)?
I download latest version from [here](http://build.chromium.org/p/client.tsan/binaries/). I wrote the test app for VS2008 (with single `printf("hello");`) and compile it.
Then `tsan.bat --log-file=logTasn.txt --color -- debug\test.exe`and see

> The application failed to initialize properly (0xc0000005). Click on
>   OK to terminate the application.

=( without any description in console. And I can't find anything about that in goolge =(
Does anyone has the same problem? Or somebody can give me recommendation?

Comment: Try to ask in mailing list of data-race-test project

Answer (score 2):

You can still run this in the Visual Studio debugger. In your solution, change the "Debugging>Command" from `$(TargetPath)` to `tsan.bat` and the "Debugging>Command Arguments" to `--log-file=logTasn.txt --color -- $(TargetPath)`.

You will then catch the Access Violation as it happens.

Comment: I entered the mentioned settings but studio says Unable to start program 'blabla/tsan.bat'. The specified file is an unrecognized or unsupported binary format.

Comment: `CMD /C blabla\tsan.bat`, then.

Comment: I enter exactly what you describe in my VS 2008 configuration, but still no luck :( It now cannot find the path specified.

Comment: Visual Studio can't find CMD, or CMD can't find tsan.bat? Because the former is rather unlikely, and the latter is really a matter of getting the path to `tsan.bat` right.

Comment: 1) cmd /c tsan ... works in cmd! 2) tsan works in cmd! 3) C:\blabla\...\tsan.bat works in cmd 4) bare cmd works in visual studio 5) tsan is giving me the errorbinary format 6) cmd /c with path or not path in tsan invocation is giving me not existance. I'll give it a more in depth look later this evening. Thank you anyway ;)

Comment: `CMD /K tsan.bat` from Visual Studio would drop you at the command prompt afterwards. That way, you can check how the environment differs.

Comment: I think we succeeded this time! I am going to check it at my work PC tomorrow. Here at home it worked. ;)

Comment: @MSalters Does this still apply for MSVS 2017? Is there any thread sanitizer available for Windows platform?

Comment: @Nik-Lz: The ability to run batch files which wrap your executable still is part of MSVC2017, works exactly the same down. The ` tsan`  project mentioned seems outdated if I follow the links .

Comment: @MSalters Yes it is outdated. I'm trying to find some alternative for Windows C++ / MSVS and I really can't. I wonder.. nobody needs that? It can't be.. I'm only seeing Application Verifier as a potential alternative, but it's not popular. I'll check it out though.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure correct Visual C++ Runtime is installed. You may download one of the from (VS2008, 32-bit, RTM): 
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=29

Comment: Visual C++ Runtime is installed 100% =) I write apps by using this VS2008.

Answer (score 0):

Timur, who's developing ThreadSanitizer for Windows, has just downloaded http://build.chromium.org/p/client.tsan/binaries/tsan-r3613-x86-windows-sfx.exe to C:\tmp , ran it to unpack TSan and it ran helloworld app without any problems, like this:
C:\tmp\tsan-x86-windows\tsan.bat -- hello.exe

btw, --color should not be needed/used when you use --log-file

Please address the further questions to data-race-test@googlegroups.com